# Questions about fourier transformation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

I understand to purpose of the fourier transformation is to transfer a PDE into an ODE. By solving the ODE and then take the inverse transform, I can get the answer.

 I have the following PDE ($\phi $ is a function of x and y, $\eta$ is a function of x):

$$ \nabla^2 \phi = 0,\quad 0<y<1, \quad(1)$$
$$ \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} = \frac{d \eta}{dx}\quad on \quad y=1, \quad (2)$$
$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}+\frac{\eta}{F^2}+P(x)=0 \quad on \quad y =1, \quad (3)$$
$$ \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}=0 \quad on \quad y=0, \quad (4)$$
$$P(x)=e^{-x^2/l^2}$$
$F$ and $l$ are constant.

Here is what I did: I tried to fourier transform equation (1), thus I get
$$\frac{\partial^2 \tilde\phi}{\partial y}-k^2 \tilde\phi=0$$
which is an ODE that I can solve, I get
$$\tilde\phi(k,y)=Ae^{ky}+Be^{-ky}$$
By plugging in my initial condition (4), I get $$A=-B$$ That means 
$$\tilde\phi(k,y)=2A\sinh(ky)$$
Here is the part I got stuck: when I am using my boundary conditions (2) and (3), there are $\eta$ in it. I get two equations: 
$$2A\cosh(k)=i\tilde\eta,$$
$$2Aik\sinh(k)+\tilde\eta / F^2+ \tilde P(k)=0$$
which I cannot solve for A 
What did I do wrong? And I'm confused because the answer gives me solution of $\eta$ not $\phi$.

The answer is $$\eta =-F^2P+\frac{F^2}{2 \pi}\  \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{k\tilde P(k)}{k-\tanh(k)/F^2} e^{ikx}\,dk.\ $$
$\tilde P(k)$ is the fourier transform of $P(x)$

Comment: There is a couple of issues before we can help you 1. You haven't specified the domain of $x$ 2. You haven't got enough boundary conditions 3. I'm not even sure your boundary conditions make sense 4. The constant $A$ should be $A(k)$

Comment: 1. I think the domain of x is any real number. 2.That's all I have. 3. Thanks for pointing out. I was wrong about that.

Comment: @reuns you mean $\tilde\phi (k,y)=2A(k)cosh(ky)$?

Comment: Right. Then $\partial_y\phi(x,y)|_{y=1} = \partial_x \eta(x)$ means (FT in $x$) $\partial_y\hat{\phi}(k,y)|_{y=1}= \partial_y (2 A(k) \cosh(ky))|_{y=1}= 2A(k) k \sinh(k)= ik \hat{\eta}(k), \hat{\eta}(k) = -2 iA(k)\sinh(k) $ and $\partial_x \phi(x,1) + F^{-2} \eta(x)+P(x)=0 $ gives (FT in $x$) $2A(k) \cosh(k) - F^{-2} 2 iA(k)\sinh(k)+ \hat{P}(k)=0$ from which you obtain $A(k)$ and $\phi(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{\phi}(k,y)e^{i kx}dk=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty 2A(k) \cosh(ky)e^{i kx}dk$